# Check for convergence :$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n!)^\frac{1}{n}} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

Establish the convergence or divergence of $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{(n!)^\frac{1}{n}} $$ using only the given nth term.

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac n{(n!)^{1/n}}\ge\frac n{(n^n)^{1/n}}$$